# Is it possible to rewrite sql stored procedure as c# code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have sql stored procedure in my database. In this stored procedure calls SQLCLR function. But I want to migrate on Azure cloud which does not support SQLCLR. So I need to get rid of this sql stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcessCampaignRecipients]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Campaigns TABLE (RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1),CampaignID INT, OwnerID INT, IsProcessed BIT, AccountID INT) 
    DECLARE @campaignsCount INT

    INSERT INTO @Campaigns
    SELECT CampaignID, CreatedBy,0, AccountID FROM Campaigns C (NOLOCK) WHERE C.IsDeleted = 0  AND C.ScheduleTime < GETUTCDATE() AND C.CampaignStatusID IN (102,106) AND (C.IsRecipientsProcessed = 0 or C.IsRecipientsProcessed is null) ORDER BY C.ScheduleTime 
ASC
    SELECT @campaignsCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) from @Campaigns)

    DECLARE @RowNumber INT = 1


    WHILE  @RowNumber <= @campaignsCount
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DeleteCounter INT = 5000
        DECLARE @CampaignID INT 
        DECLARE @OwnerID INT
        DECLARE @AccountID INT
        DECLARE @SSContacts dbo.Contact_List
        DECLARE @serviceUri VARCHAR (1024)
        DECLARE @processResponse VARCHAR (1024)
        DECLARE @isPrivate BIT
        DECLARE @ssContactsCount INT
        DECLARE @deleteIterations INT


        SELECT @CampaignID = CampaignID, @OwnerID = OwnerID,@AccountID=AccountID FROM @Campaigns WHERE RowNumber = @RowNumber --order by CampaignID OFFSET 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only
        SELECT @isPrivate= ISNULL((select top 1 IsPrivate from AccountDataAccessPermissions where accountid = @AccountID and ModuleID = 3),0)
        SELECT @processResponse = ''
        SELECT @OwnerID = 
            CASE @isPrivate 
                WHEN  0 THEN  0 
                WHEN 1 THEN @OwnerID    
            END 

        SELECT @serviceUri = Value FROM EnvironmentSettings (nolock) WHERE Name = 'SmarttouchServiceUri'

        BEGIN TRY           

              INSERT INTO  SSCONTACTS_NEW ([CampaignID],[ContactID],[MomentaryRecipientID])
              SELECT    [CampaignID],[ContactID],[MomentaryRecipientID] FROM  [dbo].[MomentaryCampaignRecipients] (NOLOCK) WHERE campaignid = @CampaignID

            print cast(@CampaignID as varchar(200))
            EXEC dbo.HandleNextCampaign @CampaignID, @OwnerID , @SSContacts
            UPDATE Campaigns SET IsRecipientsProcessed = 1 WHERE CampaignID = @CampaignID
            DELETE @SSContacts
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH     
            UPDATE Campaigns SET CampaignStatusID = 110, IsRecipientsProcessed=0, Remarks = ERROR_MESSAGE(), ProcessedDate = GETUTCDATE() WHERE CampaignID = @CampaignID
        END CATCH


        WHILE @DeleteCounter = 5000
        BEGIN
            DELETE TOP(5000) FROM MomentaryCampaignRecipients WHERE CampaignID = @CampaignID
            SET @DeleteCounter = @@ROWCOUNT
        END

        UPDATE @Campaigns SET IsProcessed = 1 WHERE RowNumber = @RowNumber      
        SET @RowNumber = @RowNumber + 1     
    END
END
```

I need to rewrite it as C# code. I am new in SQL so I don't know is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible. You must read the sql code and understand the logic. Then u should write the code

Comment: I am sure you can do something similar, so the answer is yes. Next question? However, as it stands, this question is too broad and not really a good a fit for Stackoverflow

Comment: You would also need to either call the `dbo.HandleNextCampaign` stored procedure or rewrite it too

Comment: "This stored procedure calls a CLR stored procedure, and CLR stored procedures aren't allowed. Therefore I need to replace *this* stored procedure"? Isn't the correct reaction "Therefore I need to replace the *CLR* stored procedure"?

Comment: Yes, you can. What this stored procedure is actually doing is "dbo.HandleNextCampaign" and inserting completed tasks - [CampaignID],[ContactID],[MomentaryRecipientID] to a SSCONTACTS_NEW table (if successful). You can recreate this process using a C# DataTable by leveraging Namespace:    System.Data. Just create a loop and add them.

Comment: Yes. You have to understand and workout the logic in c#, however in terms of performance it is a bad choice. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290686/converting-a-complex-stored-procedure-into-c-sharp-ado-net)

Comment: i am confused. You want to rewrite the `SQLCLR` code as `Stored Procedure` or `Stored Procedure` as `C#` ?

Comment: Stored Procedure as `C#`

Comment: isn't SQLCLR a way of using .net on SQL Server?  The procedure seems to be in TSQL as opposed to .net already.  Would you even need SQLCLR, and could you run the SQL on Azure anyway?